# I have POM model but when running Parallel test cases it fails sometimes so I want to use ThreadLocal

Tags: java, selenium

In my framework I have used POM with pageFactory implementation but now I want to run them in Parallel can anyone help me with ThreadLocal concept as I am new to it

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a restaurant. Think of a table. A table has no means to control concurrent access (like a traffic light) so it's not considered thread-safe. If there would be a single table, all guest would fight for a place to sit or half-sit on a chair. A solution would be, that every guest brings it's own table (instance variable) but that would fill up the restaurant's space. Instead, you have a table for every group of guests that. And as long as you sit on the table you have exclusive access to it and once the group of guests leave, the next group of guest may access it, so it's a shared resource without concurrent access. 
The table in the example is a ThreadLocal.

There are two options for initializing the thread local - with or without inital value.

**Without initial value**

when you have worker threads that are reused. You set the ThreadLocal when the task execution begins and may clear it, once it's done.

```
static ThreadLocal<YourType> LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<>();

void beginWork() {
   LOCAL.set(yourTypeInstance);
}
```

**With initial value**

when you want to ensure that the value is initialized and the value itself is not contextual, similar to a singleton and different to the task example.

```
static ThreadLocal<YourType> LOCAL = ThreadLocal.withInitialValue(() -> new YourType());

void beginWork() {
   YourType localInstance = LOCAL.get();
}
```

**Important!**
ThreadLocal is a concept for shared values and should always be static references, using non-static references could introduce pretty bad memory leaks (instance per-object and per-thread).

While singletons are shared resources with concurrent access option, thread locals are shared resources with sequential access. Objects in thread local do not have to be thread safe. Technically, the threadlocal objects are held in a special area of the memory to which only the thread has exclusive access.

For your concrete question, a thread local would make sense for your factory if

- your factory is not thread safe
- your factory has a state that should not be shared among threads

if you use thread local for this, use the option with inital value to create the factory once per thread used

Given the information you provided, I would suggest to fix the thread safety problems instead. The POM should easily be reusable by tests and should not have shared state (static access). Same for the factory. And you should also use a separate WebDriver per thread, but it should be perfectly alright to create one per test as an instance variable without using a thread local and assign it to the POM.

But no rule without exception, depending on the implementation model, you may have designed it around a *current context* that holds a reference to the current driver, so you could have a static getter method for the driver. In that case, ThreadLocal is the way to go.

```
class TestContext {

  static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> CURRENT_DRIVER = ThreadLocal.withInitialValue(() -> new FirefoxDriver());

  static WebDriver currentDriver(){
   return CURRENT_DRIVER.get();
  }
}

//your POM
class LoginPage {
  void login(String username) {
     TestContext.currentDriver().getElementById(...).sendKeys(username);
     //...
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @Gerald thanks for you valuable explanation. Every time calling single method is not good idea. I have to implement thread local structure where by I will initialize my WebDriver in base class and that can be reusable in  POM. Can I use "@BeforeMethod" TestNG annotation instead?

Comment: sure, its the option without initial value (see above)

Comment: Lets makes things simple if I initiailize my driver static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
@BeforeAnnotation public WebDriver getDriver() { driver.get(); }    How it will be work in my sub classes?